# How many tasks can a single thread execute simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading

How many tasks can a single thread execute simultaneously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Concurrently:** Zero or one. A thread is a thread. Not a magic yarn.

If by "in parallel" you mean "processed in parallel" *and* if you consider *awaited* Tasks, then there is no upper-bound limit on how many tasks are being awaited - but only *one* will actually be executed per a single CPU hardware-thread (usually 2x the CPU core count [due to superscalar simultaneous multithreading, aka Hyper-Threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading)).

Also remember that `Task` is very abstract. It does not refer only to concurrently executing/executed (non-blocking) code, but can also refer to pending IO (e.g. disk IO, network IO, etc) that is being handled asynchronously by the host environment (e.g. the operating system) rather than it blocking the thread if it used a "traditional" (non-asynchronous) OS API call.

---

### Re: comment

> I just have a problem with handling multiple (it can be 5000, for instance) clients on the server and for each of them, I need to run a separate handling loop. But I'm concerned about the fact that the thread can handle either 0 or 1 tasks. Does it mean I should create a new thread for every new client? I know it does not matter how much threads I'll create, it won't change speed. But speed does not matter - the loop just should be executed independently for each client.

Ugh, this is not quite the same thing as your question - but I'll try my best to explain...

> for each of them, I need to run a separate handling loop

Not necessarily. Just because you need to maintain *state* for each connected client does not mean you need a separate "loop" (i.e. a thread of execution).

In computers today fundamentally almost all network IO goes through the BSD Sockets API ("WinSock" on Windows, and in .NET this is represented via `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`). Remember that all kinds of computers work with sockets, including simple single-threaded computers. They don't need a blocking-loop for each connection: instead they use `select` to get information about socket status without blocking and only read data from the socket's input buffer if safe to do so. Voila! Only a single thread is needed. You can do this in .NET by checking `Socket.Available`, `Socket.Select`, or better yet: using the newer `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` method, for example.

If you're using BSD Sockets API (`System.Net.Sockets`) then you should use `Socket.Select`

> Does it mean I should create a new thread for every new client?

***NOOOOONONONONONNONONO** - no, you do not. Creating and running a new `Thread` for each connected client (`Socket`, `NetworkStream`, `TcpClient`, etc) is an anti-pattern that will quickly exhaust your available process memory (as each `Thread` [costs 1MB just for its default stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-stack-size) on Windows desktop, ~250KB within IIS).

> I know it does not matter how much threads I'll create

**YES IT DOES!**. Spawning lots of threads is a good way to torpedo your application's network performance and consume unnecessarily large amounts of memory.

> the loop just should be executed independently for each client.

Please learn about Asynchronous Sockets. By using the `async` feature in C# with `NetworkStream` or `Socket`'s async methods your code will use as few threads as necessary to handle network data.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I'm asking this because I just have a problem with handling multiple (it can be 5000, for instance) clients on the server and for each of them, I need to run a separate handling loop. But I'm concerned about the fact that the thread can handle either 0 or 1 tasks. Does it mean I should create a new thread for every new client? I know it does not matter how much threads I'll create, it won't change speed, bc it's up to hardware. But speed does not matter - the loop itself just should be executed independently for each client.

Comment: @NicolasIceberg I've updated my answer to reply to your comment.